# How to handle SSL SYSCALL error connection when trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, powershell, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database by using this command using my local terminal (Windows PowerShell):

```
psql -h 112.176.20.102 -p 5432 -d bookstore -U postgres -W
```

But it returns an error message as shown below:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "112.176.20.102", port 5432 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (0x00002746/10054)
connection to server at "112.176.20.102", port 5432 failed: expected authentication request from server, but received S
```

---

**1. I have set up the `pg_hba.conf` configuration as shown below:**

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
...
# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

**2. I also have set up postgresql.conf as shown below:**

```
# -----------------------------
# PostgreSQL configuration file
# -----------------------------
...
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
...
```

---

My question is what causes this problem and how to handle it so that I can connect to my remote PostgreSQL database?

Comment: The client just sent its startup packet and is now waiting for an authentication request (including "no authentication required") or an error. Instead, it got a `ParameterStatus` message from the server, which should come later. So something is messed up here. Can you see any error messages in the PostgreSQL server log? You could use a tool like Wireshark to capture the packet flow and see what messages are being sent.

Comment: Did you try `cmd.exe` instead of Powershell to run `psql`?